# Python lists: find word in list; print corresponding value from another list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists. User writes a word, if it exists in first list corresponding value from second list is used. For example it's the 3rd word, and in the list of definitions its also third. So it should print the 3rd thing in the list of definitions. I cant find help on the internet. 
I know it has something to do with length but I just don't know how to link user's answer to the list and then print the corresponding definition.

```
wordlist = ['zebra', 'piano', 'fly']
deflist = ['is an animal','is a musical instrument','is an insect']
lenwordlist = len(wordlist)
lendeflist = len(deflist)

word = wordlist(lenwordlist)
defl = deflist(lendeflist)

request = input("Write a word: ")
if request in wordlist:
    print defl
endif
```

Please help

Comment: you cant use `def` as a variable name, also you need to use square brackets `[ ]` for array indexes.

Comment: and if request in wordlist - get its index(docs for list item index)

Comment: It might be easier to use a dict instead of two lists. e.g. `d = {'zebra': 'is an animal', 'piano': 'is a musical instrument', 'fly': 'is an insect'}`. Now `d['zebra']` gives you the definition. You could even make the dict dynamically `d = dict(zip(wordlist, deflist))`.

Comment: Moreover, there is no "endif" needed in Python.

Comment: also arrays start from index `0`, so if length of array is `n` ,last element is not `n`, but `n-1`

Comment: Please take a beginner python tutorial.

Comment: @PaulRooney gave a pretty fast example. To solve your problem tho you'll need to do `for entry in wordlist: if request in entry: print('Found your word')`. You should also try to follow Python3+ syntax, there's rarely any need to not do it because most Python3 syntax will work in Python2 anyway, and Python3 is the future (soon the past)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to correlate things, use dictionaries.

```
words = dict(
    zebra = 'is an animal',
    piano = 'is a musical instrument',
    fly   = 'is an insect'
)

words['zebra']
# = 'is an animal'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. No `endif` if Python. The indentation handles it
2. `def = ...`  is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
3. `len` in not needed.

You want a list of words + their definitions. This can be done by a list of pairs , or by a dict, which is the better solution in my opinion:

```
wordlist = ['zebra', 'piano', 'fly']
deflist = ['is an animal','is a musical instrument','is an insect']

d = dict((item, definition) for item,definition in zip(wordlist,deflist))
# If you have Python 2.7 + or Python3 you may use this syntax:
# d = {item: definition for (item, definition) in zip(wordlist,deflist)}
```

From here you can ask for input:

```
request = input("Write a word: ")
```

and check in your dictionary:

```
if request in d:
    print (d[request])
```

---

All in all:

```
wordlist = ['zebra', 'piano', 'fly']
deflist = ['is an animal','is a musical instrument','is an insect']

d = dict((item, definition) for item,definition in zip(wordlist,deflist))

request = input("Write a word: ")
if request in d:
    print (d[request])
```

Comment: so can this be considered as some search algorithm?

Comment: not really IMO. a search would be sequential search or a binary search and so on... This just uses the `in` keyword of Python to search for you. Python implements the search using an algorithm

Comment: @ClsForCookies when you build the dict the comprehension is redundant. You are essentially transforming a tuple into a the same tuple. You can declare this in a more concise fashion, just `dict(zip(wordlist, deflist))`.

Answer (score 0):

Lists have an index method, like so:

```
wordlist = ['zebra', 'piano', 'fly']
deflist = ['is an animal','is a musical instrument','is an insect']
request = input("Word: ")
if request in wordlist:
    print(deflist[wordlist.index(request)])
```

However this is inefficient as it iterates over the list twice

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries links a key (the word) to a value (the definition). The syntax is as follows: (not unique)

```
words = {"zebra": "is an animal", "piano": "is a musical instrument", "fly": "is an insect"}
```

To get a definition, simply put the key inside `[]`:

```
words["zebra"] # will return "is an animal".
```

Now to work with list, you should not look at the length of the items, but at the indexation of the item in the list.

```
wordlist = ['zebra', 'piano', 'fly']
deflist = ['is an animal','is a musical instrument','is an insect']
```

The list indexes are going from `0` to `len(list)-1`. The method `index()` returns the index of an item in the list.

To get the definition of the `"fly"`, you could do this:

```
deflist[wordlist.index("fly")]
```

The elements inside the `[]` is the index, here `wordlist.index("fly")` which returns `2`. Thus `deflist[2]` will return the correct definition.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if I could use the searching algorithm for this...

Answer (score 0):

Try out this;

```
wordlist = ['zebra', 'piano', 'fly']
deflist = ['is an animal','is a musical instrument','is an insect']
def some_func(word, sentence):
  if word in wordlist:
    sentence = sentence[wordlist.index(word)]
    return word+' '+sentence
  return "Word does not have a sentence in function"
word = input("Write a word: ")
print(some_func(word, deflist))
```

Comment: Some constructive comments (hope you dont take offence) you should add some explanation to your answer, this will help the OP understand what you are proposing. Also from a readability point of view try adding some blank lines between some of the sections in your code, it will make it far easier to read (check [this](https://repl.it/repls/CautiousSeashellFiletype))and understand. Just flag this comment when you want it removed.

Answer (score -3):

As I understand you correct - you want,

If the given word is in `wordlist`
   give me the index of it
   If the given index exists on deflist:
      print the word found at specific index from deflist

But this will be heavy inefficient - better use Dictionaries

Comment: If you want to ask for a more detailed explanation, do it in the comments section, not in the answers section.